# What's the variance of intercept estimator in multiple linear regression?

Tags: linear-regression

Suppose a linear regression model
$Y=Xβ+ε$
where $X$ is an $n$-by-$(k+1)$ matrix and $\epsilon$ follows $N(0,\sigma^2I_n)$. $k$ is the number of explanatory variables. The first column of $X$ is one (intercept).

Or we can write in this form: $Y=β_0+β_1X_1+...+β_kX_k+\epsilon$

I learned from the book "Introductory Econometrics - Wooldridge" that the variance of $\hat\beta_j$ is

$\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta_j)=\sigma^2/SST_j/(1-R_j^2)$

This only holds for $j=1,...,k$. But for $\hat\beta_0$, $SST_0=0$ and it is not valid.

I have already known that $\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta)=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$ but that doesn't give an explicit formula of $\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta_0)$. Is there any clear way just like what we have on $\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta_j)$?

I also know that if $k=1$ then $\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta_0)=\sigma^2\sum x_i^2/SST_x/n$. Is there any similar result when $k>1$?

QUESTION: What is the variance of intercept estimator?

$\operatorname{var}(\hat\beta_0)=?$

Comment: This would go better on Cross Validated.SE, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your $X$ will look like this
\begin{equation}
 X = \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{1} & X_1 & \ldots & X_{k-1} 
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{1}$ is an all-ones vectors of size $N$ and $X_{j}$ is the $(j+1)^{th}$ column in $X$
Then 
\begin{equation}
 X^T X 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1} & \bar{y}^T \\
  \bar{y} & Y^T T
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Notice that we have a block matrix here. Also notice that $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1} = N$, with 
\begin{equation}
 \bar{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \sum X_{1i} \\
  \vdots \\
  \sum X_{Ni} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
an $Y$ is the matrix $X$ with first column being omitted. 
\begin{equation}
 X^T X 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  N & \bar{y}^T \\
  \bar{y} & Y^T T
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Using block matrix inversion, we get that the first element in the first row of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ is 
\begin{equation}
 [(X^T X)^{-1}]_{1,1}
 =
 N^{-1} + N^{-1} \bar{y}^T(Y^T Y -  \bar{y} N^{-1} \bar{y}^T )^{-1}\bar{y}N^{-1}
\end{equation}
Since $N$ is a scalar this simplifies to
\begin{equation}
 [(X^T X)^{-1}]_{1,1}
 =
 \frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{N^2} \bar{y}^T(Y^T Y -  
 \frac{1}{N}\bar{y} \bar{y}^T )^{-1}\bar{y} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
But 
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{var} (\hat{\beta}_0) 
 =
 \sigma^2 [(X^T X)^{-1}]_{1,1} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
So using $(1)$ in $(2)$ we get
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{var} (\hat{\beta}_0) 
 =
  \frac{\sigma^2}{N} + \frac{\sigma^2}{N^2} \bar{y}^T(Y^T Y -  
 \frac{1}{N}\bar{y} \bar{y}^T )^{-1}\bar{y}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you. Is there any result with a form like $var(β_j)=σ^2/SST_j/(1−R^2_j)$?

Comment: SST stands for Total sum of squares ?

Comment: $SST_j$ is the sum of $(X_{i,j}-\bar X_j)^2$ where $\bar X_j$ is the mean value of $j$-th column of $X$.